# SQL/PHP get a Selection from 2 Tables

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I have 2 Tables and i need to hide a multiple result.

My Tables:

```
aID Name
 1  aaa
 2  bbb


aID Stuff
 1   01
 1   02
 1   06
 2   01
 2   03
```

My result looks like this:

```
 1   aaa  01
 1   aaa  02
 1   aaa  06
 2   bbb  01
 2   bbb  03
```

How can i display the result in HTML/PHP that it looks like this:

```
1 aaa 01,02,06
2 bbb 01,03
```

Comment: Google:  `MySQL group_concat`.

Comment: place your code here what have yo tried ??

Comment: `Select aID, Name, GROUP_CONCAT(Stuff) as concat_stuff FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 using (aID) group by aID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `group_concat` along with `group by` clause, instead of using `HTML/PHP` you can simply get it from sql using query as

```
select a.aID, a.Name, Group_concat(b.stuff) as stuff
from user a join stuff b on a.aID = b.aID
group by aID
order by aID, Name ASC
```

Note: Table name are arbitrary over here please place your table names

Comment: thanks alot, only "user a join stuff b" change with "table1 join table2"

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your query

> GROUP_CONCAT(Stuff) As Stuff  //Where you select your Stuff
>
> GROUP BY aID  //At the end

Answer (score 0):

This is just the syntax change it as per your need.
Hope this may help you.

```
select id, group_concat(`Name` separator ',') as `ColumnName`
from
(
select id, concat(`Name`, ':',
group_concat(`Value` separator ',')) as `Name`
from mytbl
group by id, `Name`
) tbl
group by id;
```